# Hangup caller and callee simultaneously

Tags: asterisk, ivr

In asterisk, If caller hangup his call,callee remain connected and vice versa. Basically I want if anyone of caller or callee hangup the call both legs of the call should be hangup.. Is there any way please guide??? I will be very thankful.

Answer (score 0):

In asterisk if caller or callee hangup, both hangup imidiatly

Unless you have 'g' in dial or other special things to continue dialplan execution from caller side.

If caller hangup asterisk will hangup called ALWAYS. No any special way prevent that,except maybe calling via conference as two calls.

If any side not hangup with your setup, troubleshoot your voip provider.